# How can I propagate touch event in nested Touchable in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my app I have a nested Touchable element.
Every time I press on one of them, I got only one event.
Can I propagate the inner downward the layer?
Thanks in advance!

Code as follow:

```
    <TouchableHighlight style={{ flex: 1 }} onPress={() => { console.log('outer press') }}>
        <TouchableHighlight style={{ flex: 0.8, backgroundColor: 'blue' }} onPress={() => { console.log('inner press') }}>
            <Text>1</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    </TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: @PritishVaidya I created a snack here: https://snack.expo.io/@dgellow/restless-pizza

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A `Touchables` contains one local state, that is native to it and the other `Touchables` are **not aware of it.**

So when you touch a nested `Touchable`, the event gets propogated to the child element that access the state and does not release the resource unless it is complete

Here would be the life cycle in your case for the nested `buttons`, as mentioned in the [`docs`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system.html)

```
Parent: Parent Touchable
Child: Child Touchable

Parent onStartShouldSetResponder > Parent onResponderGrant > Parent onResponderTerminationRequest > Parent onResponderTerminate > Child onStartShouldSetResponder > Child onResponderGrant > Child onResponderRelease
```

*Parent will not get access due to `onResponderReject`*

> If a parent `View` wants to prevent the child from becoming responder on a touch start, it should have a `onStartShouldSetResponderCapture` handler which returns `true`.

You may have a look into this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBYPqb83C7k)

Comment: Thx for your answer. For others want to have more details. You can search for `onStartShouldSetResponder` and `onStartShouldSetResponderCapture`

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by avoiding two nested Touchable* components. Using the `onStartShouldSetResponderCapture`  or `pointerEvents` wasn't successful for what I tried to achieve.

Instead, I ended up using a view and its `onTouchStart` event, as it triggers in addition to the nested onPress event of a Touchable component. I still had to use `pointerEvents="box-none"` on the outer View.

```
<View
      pointerEvents="box-none"
      onTouchStart={(evt: GestureResponderEvent) => console.log("outerHandler")}>
       <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={(evt: GestureResponderEvent) => console.log("innerHandler")}>
              <Text>Press me</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Answer (score -4):

Wouldn't you just remove the onPress for the outer? I am not sure I understand the question but try using `event.preventDefault` on the outer touchable highlight, to only access the inner one.

```
<TouchableHighlight style={{ flex: 1 }} onPress={(event) => { event.preventDefault() }}>
    <TouchableHighlight style={{ flex: 0.8, backgroundColor: 'blue' }} onPress={() => { console.log('inner press') }}>
        <Text>1</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
</TouchableHighlight>
```