# How to let long press event bubble up in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How do I make the long press event bubble up such that both triggered 1 and triggered 2 are printed?

```
  <Pressable style={styles.press2} onLongPress={() => { console.log('triggered 2') }}>
    <Text>Look Down</Text>
    <ScrollView>
      <Pressable style={{styles.press1}} onLongPress={() => { console.log('triggered 1') }}>
        <Text>click me</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </ScrollView>
  </Pressable>
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49850506) answer but I really don't understand it

**Edit:** is there any way to solve this without importing another package?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is easily doable without a 'hacky' enable trick. I would personally use a `LongPressGestureHandler` from `react-native-gesture-handler`.

They have a `simultaneousHandlers` prop which makes multiple handlers work at the same time, so you could do something like this:

```
const childHandlerRef = useRef(null);

<LongPressGestureHandler simultaneousHandlers={childHandlerRef}>
  <View>
    <LongPressGestureHandler ref={childHandlerRef}>
      // other components
    </LongPressGestureHandler>
  </View>
</LongPressGestureHandler>
```

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/api/gesture-handlers/common-gh#simultaneoushandlers).

Comment: looks promising but also hacky like you said but I'm sure there must be some way to do it without importing another package, any ideas?

Comment: I ment that with the default pressable you probably need a hacky workaround. This is common practice in react-native-gesture-handler. I don't think it is easily doable without a third party library.